# Playing RTSP in WPF application with low latency using FFMPEG / FFMediaElement (FFME)

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm trying to use [FFMediaElement](https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement) (FFME, WPF MediaElement replacement based on FFmpeg) component to play RSTP live video in my WPF application.

I have a good connection to my camera and I want to play it with minimum available latency.

I've reduced the latency by changing `ProbeSize` to its minimal value:

```
private void Media_OnMediaInitializing(object Sender, MediaInitializingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  e.Configuration.GlobalOptions.ProbeSize = 32;
}
```

But I still have about 1 second of latency since the very beginning of the stream. I mean, when I start playing, I have to wait for 1 second till the video appears and then I have 1s of latency.

I've also tried to change following parameters:

```
e.Configuration.GlobalOptions.EnableReducedBuffering = true;
e.Configuration.GlobalOptions.FlagNoBuffer = true;
e.Configuration.GlobalOptions.MaxAnalyzeDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

but it gave no result.

I measured time-interval between FFmpeg output lines (the number in the first column is the time, elapsed from the previous line, ms)

```
 ----     OpenCommand: Entered
   39     FFInterop.Initialize: FFmpeg v4.0
    0     EVENT START: MediaInitializing
    0     EVENT DONE : MediaInitializing
  379     EVENT START: MediaOpening
    0     EVENT DONE : MediaOpening
    0     COMP VIDEO: Start Offset:      0,000; Duration:        N/A
   41     SYNC-BUFFER: Started.
  609     SYNC-BUFFER: Finished. Clock set to 1534932751,634
    0     EVENT START: MediaOpened
    0     EVENT DONE : MediaOpened
    0     EVENT START: BufferingStarted
    0     EVENT DONE : BufferingStarted
    0     OpenCommand: Completed
    0     V BLK: 1534932751,634 | CLK: 1534932751,634 | DFT:    0 | IX:   0 | PQ:     0,0k | TQ:     0,0k
    0     Command Queue (1 commands): Before ProcessNext
    0        Play - ID: 404 Canceled: False; Completed: False; Status: WaitingForActivation; State: 
   94     V BLK: 1534932751,675 | CLK: 1534932751,699 | DFT:   24 | IX:   1 | PQ:     0,0k | TQ:     0,0k
```

So, the most the process of "sync-buffering" takes the most of the time.

Is there any parameter of FFmpeg which allows reducing a size of the buffer?

Comment: What codec are you using? (MJPEG, H.264, ... ) Does the software facilitate your GPU for decoding the stream? How much delay would you consider "acceptable" (hint: it will never be 0)? Is your cam a "premium" brand medium-to-high price segment or some discounter-stuff?

Comment: I use an H.264 codec with GOP=8 and 25fps.
When I use GStreamer (not as a part of my application), I can specify `rtspsrc` parameter `latency` as 100ms which makes an accessible result.

Comment: Does the decoder have something like a warm-up? I darkly remember something like that as an issue I once ran into ... a long time ago in a galaxy far far way ...

Comment: I don't know, tbh.
I guess, the problem is somehow related to the RTP buffer or something like that. I think I should reduce its size somehow.

Comment: That's also a possibility, yes.

Comment: 1 second sounds pretty good to me. The decoder needs to allow a little buffering room so that the frames can be displayed smoothly,  i.e. with the proper timing intervals between frames being presented. The receiving client computer does not receive the incoming RTP packets off the internet with perfect timing so some buffering is usually required.

Comment: @Paboka - since you are comparing your WPF example to gstreamer, are both using TCP for RTSP? If gstreamer uses UDP and your WPF uses TCP that could also impact the initial delay.

Comment: GStreamer uses UDP. With my WPF application, I've tried both: UDP and TCP transport, but it gave no visible effect on the latency.

Comment: According to the message-log, the most time-taking procedure is filling a SYNC-BUFFER. I guess, there should be a way to reduce it.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of FFME. It's a common question. In addition to the container configuration options in your MediaInitializing event, you could handle the `MediaOpening` event and change the following options: (This only applies to version 4.1.280 and above)

```cs
    // You can render audio and video as it becomes available but the downside of disabling time
    // synchronization is that video and audio will run on their own independent clocks.
    // Do not disable Time Sync for streams that need synchronized audio and video.
    e.Options.IsTimeSyncDisabled =
        e.Info.Format == "libndi_newtek" ||
        e.Info.InputUrl.StartsWith("rtsp://uno");

    // You can disable the requirement of buffering packets by setting the playback
    // buffer percent to 0. Values of less than 0.5 for live or network streams are not recommended.
    e.Options.MinimumPlaybackBufferPercent = e.Info.Format == "libndi_newtek" ? 0 : 0.5;

    // The audio renderer will try to keep the audio hardware synchronized
    // to the playback position by default.
    // A few WMV files I have tested don't have continuous enough audio packets to support
    // perfect synchronization between audio and video so we simply disable it.
    // Also if time synchronization is disabled, the recommendation is to also disable audio synchronization.
    Media.RendererOptions.AudioDisableSync =
        e.Options.IsTimeSyncDisabled ||
        e.Info.InputUrl.EndsWith(".wmv");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will apply to WPF but I've used this code to reduce the latency on the Microsoft H.264 decoder using C++ with WIN32 API. But even with this, I still get a short delay at startup (.5s to 1s estimated) but it is better than default. The decoder still sucks a few incoming packets before it starts spitting out. Not sure if it will improve on your 1 second latency though. Here's some of the code to give you an idea what is involved.

```
IMFTransform* pDecoderTransform;
// ...Set up pDecoderTransform
ICodecAPI* mpCodecAPI = NULL;
hr = pDecoderTransform->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&mpCodecAPI));

VARIANT var;
var.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;
hr = mpCodecAPI->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode, &var);
```